# mysql_fetch return undefined value

Tags: php, mysql

This is my PHP code so far

```
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","db_name");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $result_set = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT points FROM total WHERE id = 1");
    $row = mysql_fetch($result_set);
    $old_total = $row['total'];
    $new_total = $old_total + $_REQUEST['total'];
    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE total SET points = $new_total WHERE id = 1");
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

when i run this it returns this error:
**Call to undefined function mysql_fetch()** am i missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use $row['points'] instead of $row['total'] with mysqli_fecth_array/assoc.

Try below code:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","db_name");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result_set = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT points FROM total WHERE id = 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_set);
$old_total = $row['points'];
$new_total = $old_total + $_REQUEST['total'];
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE total SET points = $new_total WHERE id = 1");
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `mysqli_fetch` instead of `mysql_fetch`.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use

```
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_set);
```

istead of

```
  $row = mysqli_fetch($result_set);
```

hope it will be usefull......

Comment: I mixed 3 answers to get the correct code... thanks all:
`$result_set = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT points FROM total WHERE id = 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_set);
$old_total = $row['points'];
$new_total = $old_total + $_REQUEST['total'];
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE total SET points = $new_total WHERE id = 1");
mysqli_close($con);
?>`

Answer (score 0):

Final Code:

```
$result_set = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT points FROM total WHERE id = 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_set);
$old_total = $row['points'];
$new_total = $old_total + $_REQUEST['total'];
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE total SET points = $new_total WHERE id = 1");
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```